# Docker run command with -v flag puts container in Exited status

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to map a local directory `/home/ubuntu/data` to `/var/lib/mysql` folder in container by using `-v` flag but container's status becomes `Exited (0) 1`. However, if I don't use `-v` flag at all, container is `Up` but this is not what I want. What could be the reason? I see `volume mount` line is missing in event logs opposed to working example.

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server \
 && sed -i "s/127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0/g" /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf \
 && mkdir /var/run/mysqld \
 && chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld

VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql"]

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["mysqld_safe"]
```

**This is the which doesn't work.**

```
$ docker run -i -t -d -v /home/ubuntu/data:/var/lib/mysql --name mysql_container mysql_image
```

Event logs.

```
2017-11-... container create 08b44c094... (image=mysql_image, name=mysql_container)

2017-11-... network connect 62bb211934... (container=08b44c094..., name=bridge, type=bridge)

2017-11-... container start 08b44c094... (image=mysql_image, name=mysql_container)

2017-11-... container die 08b44c094... (exitCode=0, image=mysql_image, name=mysql_container)

2017-11-... network disconnect 62bb211934... (container=08b44c094..., name=bridge, type=bridge)
```

Container logs.

```
$ docker logs -t mysql_container
2017-11-... mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2017-11-... mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-11-... mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

**This works without -v**

```
$ docker run -i -t -d --name mysql_container mysql_image
```

Event logs.

```
2017-11-... container create 84993141... (image=mysql_image, name=mysql_container)

2017-11-... network connect 62bb2119... (container=84993141..., name=bridge, type=bridge)

2017-11-... volume mount 8c36b53d33... (container=84993141...7, destination=/var/lib/mysql, driver=local, propagation=, read/write=true)

2017-11-... container start 84993141... (image=mysql_image, name=mysql_container)
```

Container logs.

```
$ docker logs -t mysql_container
2017-11-... mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2017-11-... mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-11-... mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2017-11-... mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Comment: Why don't you use the mysql container ? https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/

Comment: Because I am experimenting things to learn as I am novice at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little complicated but interesting case.

So how you can check what's happening? Use following command:

```
docker run -i -t  -v /tmp/data:/var/lib/mysql  mysql_image bash
```

Now you are inside container so let's try command:

```
mysqld_safe
```

And it's ending but let's look into `/var/log/mysql/error.log`
We see there:

```
2017-11-25T17:22:24.006180Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2017-11-25T17:22:24.006211Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
2017-11-25T17:22:24.006221Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
2017-11-25T17:22:24.006229Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
2017-11-25T17:22:24.006237Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile './ibdata1'
```

Ok let's see how `/var/lib/mysql` looks without volume mapping:

```
root@4474b1cd4300:/var/lib/mysql# ls -lah
total 109M
drwx------ 5 mysql mysql 4.0K Nov 25 17:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root  root  4.0K Nov 25 17:13 ..
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql   56 Nov 25 17:13 auto.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root     0 Nov 25 17:13 debian-5.7.flag
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  419 Nov 25 17:13 ib_buffer_pool
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  48M Nov 25 17:13 ib_logfile0
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  48M Nov 25 17:13 ib_logfile1
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  12M Nov 25 17:13 ibdata1
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql 4.0K Nov 25 17:13 mysql
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql 4.0K Nov 25 17:13 performance_schema
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql  12K Nov 25 17:13 sys
```

1. mysql:mysql is owner of that directory
2. We have a lot mysql specific files there

Let's see what we've got with volume mapping:

```
root@fca45ee1e8fb:/var/lib/mysql# ls -lah
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov 25 17:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Nov 25 17:13 ..
```

1. Docker is mapping this directory as root user
2. Docker is mapping this directory into host so all files disappear because on host machine that directory is empty

How to get this work?
Change your command to:

```
CMD chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql && if [ ! -c /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 ]; then mysqld --initialize-insecure; fi && mysqld_safe
```

What's happening there?

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql - get back mysql:mysql owner
if [ ! -c /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 ]; then mysqld --initialize-insecure; fi - recreate mysql files with root user without pass but only if files not already exists (required for next runs)
mysqld_safe - run mysql
```

Comment: Is this what you mean? `CMD ["chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql && mysqld --initialize-insecure && mysqld_safe"]`

Comment: I followed your debugging steps and all worked fine. However, if change `CMD ["mysqld_safe"]` to `CMD ["chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql && mysqld --initialize-insecure && mysqld_safe"]`, I get `--initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting` error while running `docker run .....` unless I misunderstand you.

Comment: No no, I gave you proper CMD instruction (without [ ] array and without " "), see here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd
"Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. "
We need shell for && getting work :)

Comment: Nearly there! First try with `docker run -i -t -d -v /home/ubuntu/data:/var/lib/mysql --name my_con my_img` command worked fine. The `/home/ubuntu/data` folder is full. I then deleted `my_con` and recreated with same command but this time the container is not `Up`. It is `Exited`. When I run `docker run -i -t -v /home/ubuntu/data:/var/lib/mysql my_img` I get same error above which is `--initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting`.

Comment: sure! I edited my answer to match these requirements! (added simple if)

Comment: It works fine now! The only problem was `-c` flag which needed to be `-f` so all fine now. Thank you for your help. I think it is better to extract it into a `.sh` file cos it look a bit ugly :) One last thing, is it normal to have this permission (it was set automatically)? `drwxr-xr-x 6 _apt   input  4096 Nov 25 19:42 data`